# using a trigger to run a plugin with different id multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

so i have some code that works basically when a person chooses a new movie a list is appended to.

```
$("#optionalSearchOptions ul").append("<li><div class='button' style='position:relative'><select id='"+ movie.id+"' class='populate select2' style='width:200px'><option></option></select></div></li>");
```

this works fine

where that list is appended to I also invoke a trigger because that select box needs to be converted

here is the trigger

```
    $(window).trigger('convertBoxes', [movie.id, movie.title] );
```

so i have this on doc ready

```
$(window).on('convertBoxes', function (event, param1, param2){

       var tmpName = "#" + param1 ;
       console.log(param1, param2);
       $(tmpName).select2({
            placeholder: param2
       });
});
```

the problem is this runs slect 2 the first time but doesnt any time after because I am guess  the name is setup - is there a way round this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could `destroy` select2 and then reinit it.

I saw a destroy function in [Select 2 docs](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). Usage would be something like this i guess :

```
//place this before u initialize select 2
$(tmpName).select2("destroy");
```

Comment: $(window).on('convertBoxes', function (event, param1, param2){
    $(tmpName).select2("destroy");
    var tmpName = "#" + param1 ;
    console.log(param1, param2);
    $(tmpName).select2({
 placeholder: param2
   });  });

doesnt work :(

Comment: no error just doesnt apply the select 2 affects to second box just shows a normal select box

Comment: can u make a fiddle for your problem? It'll help a lot to fix it

Comment: destroy isnt really what i want to do as it just resets the invidual box - seems you cant just use a class to setup multiple instances

Comment: maybe if i created a function where pass id to it it could instansiate a new select2 instance?

Comment: ok i have edited your fiddle to have my code jsfiddle.net/dwhitmarsh/MfJ4B/5 try adding a movie then adding another